# Python 3 Pygame programs will not quit

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

When the pygame window closes, I want to immediately stop execution; that's the end of the program. I have looked up and down the internet and every problem I come across is something like "Did you try `pygame.quit()`" or "You never break out of your infinite loop". That isn't my problem. Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pygame
from sys import exit as sysExit

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((512,512))
screen.fill((255,255,255))

pygame.display.update()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.display.quit()
            pygame.quit()
            exit(0)
            sysExit(0)
            #None of these work, code under them is unreachable but the process hangs
```

As the comment and question title say, this process hangs. I honestly don't what else I could do to tell python I'm done, and I've tried every combination of these quit functions but nothing works. The window will close, but the program never ends. In my searching I've found people have issues with something called "IDLE" which I do not have.

Here's what I *do* have (my system): Linux Mint Cinnamon 18, 32-bit (i686), using python version 3.5.2 (no IDE, just running from terminal)

EDIT - Apparently there's some confusion about what I'm talking about when I say the program "hangs", so here's some screenshots of the issue in action. This first one shows you that the above code is, in fact, usable to reproduce the problem.
[image: Program]
Now all I do is run this script, and it just gives me a blank window like you'd expect.
[image: What happens when I run program]
Now I click the "x" button on the window, and the window disappears, but my terminal is left like this. The screen capture won't show you the blinking cursor, but you'll notice there's no new prompt.
[image: What happens when the program is done running]
I've so far been resorting to doing this to get the thing to stop:
[image: How I have to stop program]
throw it in the background, force kill the job (`SIGTERM` gets ignored btw) and foreground it again and now I have a prompt.

Comment: is your `if` statement getting executed?

Comment: Yeah, it must be, because the display is quitting properly.

Comment: What exactly hangs? Do you mean the code in the while loop still runs, even though you've closed the window? Then show us a complete example. The code you've posted should quit the program. Calling `pygame.quit()` and `sys.exit()` is the standard way to quit.

Comment: An IDE is an Integrated Development Environment, which basically is the program you use to write code. IDLE is Python's own IDE, which you get when downloading Python. I ran this code just fine; it terminated as it's supposed to. So what IDE are you using? And have you confirmed that other python programs terminates as they are supposed to?

Comment: @skrx This is a complete example, I can copy and paste this code into a file and it will hang, just like I said. I'm well aware that the code I've posted _*should*_ quit the program, I'm telling you it doesn't, and that's the problem.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman I'm not using an IDE, just a text editor and a terminal. Every script I write that uses pygame hangs like this, and every script I write without pygame quits normally.

Comment: Would it be helpful if I posted a series of screenshots? I could also take a video, but I'd need to link to it on an external site which I'm pretty sure is frowned upon since the link could spontaneously expire.

Comment: @bfieck It could be helpful to provide videos or photos. There's no problem to have links in your question that might brake, as long as your question isn't dependent on the link. In other words; if the question makes sense despite the link being broken there's no harm in adding it.

Comment: I went with screenshots after all, it's much easier.

Comment: Try using `while running:` where running is a variable(which is truthy) then make it falsy when the user attempts to quit, don't do anything else besides that.

Comment: @Nick I just gave it a shot; same problem. To be specific, if I do "nothing else", that is just end-of-file under the while without any `pygame.quit()` or `sys.exit()` etc., my process still hangs and as a bonus the window doesn't disappear. If I put in my exit stuff, same issue (tried different combinations again too, no dice)

Comment: Strange problem. What happens when you run the program by double clicking on the .py file? Does it still run in the background after you close it? On Windows your program exits correctly.

Comment: If I double click it from a desktop environment it _looks like_ it runs fine, but I can see the process still "running" in `htop`

Comment: Maybe you should inform the Pygame devs. You can find the project on [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issues?status=new&status=open). Or ask on the [mailinglist](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/info) first.

Comment: Well, bitbucket is moving slow, I'll ask the mailing list.

Comment: mailing list hasn't responded. Running low on options. Just want everyone to know I haven't forgotten about this question, and I'm still looking for an answer to put down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check pygame.init() -> (numpass, numfails), then loading each module manually (yes, each module has an init() and quit() method). I would suspect the mixed or music module to be the problem (due to os/driver/hardware issues).

Answer (score 0):

The pygame irc channel helped me figure this out. Specifically, this answer comes from user DR0ID_ who walked me through some debugging I should've thought of in the first place.

First of all, once I'm done with this answer I'll edit the question, but I have to apologize for leaving something out initially: I'm doing all this on a Virtualbox VM. By walking through the different modules initialized by `pygame.init()`, I discovered that the one that actually hangs it is `pygame.mixer`. No word yet from the pygame devs, but the working theory is that this is related to Virtualbox sound drivers and/or their interface with the host drivers. Basically, if you're on a virtual machine and don't need to play sounds, the workaround is to only initialize the modules you need. Since in my example I only need `pygame.display`, the solution is easy:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pygame

pygame.display.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((512, 512))
screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
pygame.display.update()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.display.quit()
            exit()
```